# Any way to get Pages to write Open Office format?

Tags: macos, plugins, openoffice-writer, iwork-pages

Is there some sort of plugin out there that allows Apple Pages to export Open Office document format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the stuff I found says to take it through Microsoft Word format. I'd be interested to see if you find something.